# Importing Archived TweetStream Twitter Ouput into Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have around 1000 lines of twitter data captured using python
tweetstream. The data was collected using the simple tweetstream
example of:

```
>>> stream = tweetstream.SampleStream("username", "password")
>>> for tweet in stream:
...     print tweet
```

which outputs like:

```
{u'user': {u'follow_request_sent': None,
u'profile_use_background_image': True,
u'profile_background_image_url_https': u'https://si0.twimg.com/
profile_background_images/
181013334/25957_1367646636642_1395984493_31038644_61586_n.jpg',
u'verified': False, u'profile_image_url_https': u'https://
si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1820265868/rosajennifer_normal.jpg',
u'profile_sidebar_fill_color': u'DDEEF6', u'id': 46478005,
u'profile_text_color': u'333333', u'followers_count': 505,
u'protected': False, u'location': u'', u'default_profile_image':
False, u'listed_count': 4, u'utc_offset': -21600, u'statuses_count':
35923, u'description': u'Take me as I am or watch me as I go. . .\n
\n', u'friends_count': 315, u'profile_link_color': u'0084B4',
u'profile_image_url': u'http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1820265868/
rosajennifer_normal.jpg', u'notifications': None,
u'show_all_inline_media': True, u'geo_enabled': False,
u'profile_background_color': u'C0DEED', u'id_str': u'46478005',
u'profile_background_image_url': u'http://a2.twimg.com/
profile_background_images/
181013334/25957_1367646636642_1395984493_31038644_61586_n.jpg',
u'name': u'rosa jennifer', u'lang': u'en', u'following': None,
u'profile_background_tile': True, u'favourites_count': 82,
u'screen_name': u'rosajennifer', u'url': u'http://www.facebook.com/
profile.php?ref=profile&id=1329240058', u'created_at': u'Thu Jun 11
20:11:28 +0000 2009', u'contributors_enabled': False, u'time_zone':
u'Central Time (US & Canada)', u'profile_sidebar_border_color':
u'C0DEED', u'default_profile': False, u'is_translator': False},
u'favorited': False, u'contributors': None, u'entities':
{u'user_mentions': [{u'indices': [1, 14], u'id': 90939650, u'id_str':
u'90939650', u'name': u'Dajuan(Dae-John)', u'screen_name':
u'Juan_Ton5oup'}], u'hashtags': [], u'urls': []}, u'text':
u'\u201c@Juan_Ton5oup: Spanish girls love jeans with animals outlined
on the back pockets.\u201dfoh lmao', u'created_at': u'Tue Feb 14
00:27:32 +0000 2012', u'truncated': False, u'retweeted': False,
u'in_reply_to_status_id': None, u'coordinates': None, u'id':
169216166617817088, u'source': u'<a href="http://twitter.com/#!/
download/ipad" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPad</a>',
u'in_reply_to_status_id_str': None, u'in_reply_to_screen_name': None,
u'id_str': u'169216166617817088', u'place': None, u'retweet_count': 0,
u'geo': None, u'in_reply_to_user_id_str': None,
u'in_reply_to_user_id': None}
```

I have a single file of ~1000 of these, each on a seperate line. I've
tried mongoimport as well as a dozen other methods but I can't seem to
get this data imported. Mongoimport passes back this error:

```
Sat Mar 10 12:51:00 Assertion: 10340:Failure parsing JSON string near:
u'user': {
0x581762 0x528994 0xaa29f3 0xaa4ca3 0xa9b7dd 0xa9f772 0x34df82169d
0x4fe679
 mongoimport(_ZN5mongo11msgassertedEiPKc+0x112) [0x581762]
 mongoimport(_ZN5mongo8fromjsonEPKcPi+0x444) [0x528994]
 mongoimport(_ZN6Import8parseRowEPSiRN5mongo7BSONObjERi+0x8b3)
[0xaa29f3]
 mongoimport(_ZN6Import3runEv+0x16e3) [0xaa4ca3]
 mongoimport(_ZN5mongo4Tool4mainEiPPc+0x169d) [0xa9b7dd]
 mongoimport(main+0x32) [0xa9f772]
 /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed) [0x34df82169d]
 mongoimport(__gxx_personality_v0+0x3d1) [0x4fe679]
exception:Failure parsing JSON string near: u'user': {
```

I assume this is because the string is not actual json, it's some sort
of (json like) format.

Can anyone help?

Comment: OK, first off I've figured out that the data I have is not JSON it's a python dictionary. I guess the next step it convert it somehow into json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works, I had some issues with AST but managed to get past them once I updated python on my system. This script reads in a file line by line in python dictionary format and outputs valid JSON for import into MongoDB.

```
import json
import ast

mydict = open('data.txt', 'r')
for line in mydict:
        line = ast.literal_eval(line)
        line = json.dumps(line)
        print line
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem as you noted, the following is not valid JSON, it's a python dictionary: `{u'indices':`.

Second problem, why are you trying to use `mongoimport`? In python you can just save the dictionary to the database. This is basically the first example of how to use MongoDB.

```
>>> from pymongo import Connection
>>> connection = Connection('localhost', 27017)
>>> db = connection.test_database
>>> posts = db.posts
>>> stream = tweetstream.SampleStream("username", "password")
>>> for tweet in stream:
...     posts.insert(post)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did actually figured out that it was a python dictionary and am now working on getting it into mongodb. I can't use the method you show above, the captures from tweetstream were provided to me from a previous research project. So the data has already be captured, I have to convert it.